# solve nonlinear second order ODE

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I obtained Nonlinear second order differential equation as $y\cdot y''+y'^2-m\cdot y^{-a}y'^2+k=0$, Where $y'= \dfrac{dy}{dx}$, $y''=\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}$. 
I could not obtain the solution so please help me for getting the solution of above equations with proper initial conditions.

Comment: Nonlinear ODE? I didnt even know you can solve these... Is there any other method than just guessing a solution?

Comment: is $m$ is a constant? Can you use Frobenius's method? I am guessing probably not

Comment: Any information about $m,a,k$?

Comment: Have you tried using the identity $y^{''} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dy}}\left(y^{'}\right)^{2}$ to transform the original equation to 
$$
y\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{dy}} + (1-my^{-\alpha})V + k = y\left[\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{dy}} + \frac{(1-my^{-\alpha})}{y}V + \frac{k}{y} \right]=0
$$ where $V=\left(y^{'}\right)^{2}$. You can take it from there to solve for V and then maybe $y^{'}$.